# Vincenty distance transform into array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geopy

My question is simple. From `geopy.distance`, I can calculate the distance between two points. But I can not transform the data format for further computation.

Code like this:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
length = vincenty((38.103414282108375, 114.51898800000002),\
                  (38.07902986076924, 114.50882128404997))

ration = np.array(([2,2],[3,3]))*length
```

Error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'vincenty'

I tried to change the `Distance(xxx)` into np.array: `np.array(length)`, but failed.   It shows like `array(Distance(388.659276576), dtype=object)`, still can't support for computation directly.

Comment: FWIW, if you'd like to use a more stable & more accurate algorithm than Vincenty, take a look at C. F. F Karney's excellent [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/). Some info is also give in Wikipedia's [Geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Solution_of_the_inverse_problem); Karney is a major contributor to that article, and most other Wikipedia articles on ellipsoid geodesics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the manual, you need to "export" your distance/vincenty in some format. E.g. like this:

```
> from geopy.distance import vincenty
> newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
> cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
> print(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
538.3904451566326
```

You can not process `vincenty` iteself, because (as you already mentioned) it is an object out of geopy that does not support mathematical operands. You need to extract the values inside the data object, e.g. with `.miles`. See the full documentation for other possible values: [GeoPy documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/index.html?highlight=distance#)

See the differences in types:

```
> type(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh))
geopy.distance.vincenty

> type(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
float
```

Now you can calculate with this:

```
> vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles
538.3904451566326

> vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles * 2
1076.7808903132652
```

Or, if you really need a numpy array out of this:

```
> np.array(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
array(538.3904451566326)

> type(np.array(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles))
numpy.ndarray
```

**EDIT**: Note that you can even enforce it's data type with NumPy's built-in `dtype` parameter:

```
> np.array(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles, dtype=np.float32)
array(538.3904418945312, dtype=float32)

> np.array(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles, dtype=np.float64)
array(538.3904451566326)  # dtype=float64, default type here

> np.array(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles, dtype=np.int32)
array(538, dtype=int32)
```

This *could* be helpful, if you're storing/loading lots of data but always just need a certain precision.

Comment: I had thought of that. But I still can't find a solution to save the `print` contents as np.array.

Comment: I've added an example for this. However, I would recommend that you read some NumPy and/or Python tutorial, since this is really *basic* knowledge. If you print a `float` with `print(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)` it should be *very obvious* that you can simply do `someVariable = vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles` to get that float and save it in a variable for further computation (or into a numpy array).

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Do not forget to look up some tutorials ;)

Comment: If you load/store lots of values and do not need 64bit (or even higher) precision, you can save computation time as well as memory by specifying the data type of the numpy array. See my *edit* in my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
vincenty((38.103414282108375, 114.51898800000002),\
                  (38.07902986076924, 114.50882128404997))
```

It is object and you are trying multiplication on different type object.
I would suggest do this

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
length = vincenty((38.103414282108375, 114.51898800000002),\
                  (38.07902986076924, 114.50882128404997))
length = length.miles

ration = np.array(([2,2],[3,3]))*length
```